# Naming conventions when using (PHP5) namespaces?

Tags: plugin-development

Provided you are working on a php 5.3+ only package what are the namespace conventions when it comes to plugins

```
Funky_Monki\Banana_Blogger_Plugin\Admin::Banana_Tosser

Plugins\Funky_Monkey_Banana_Blogger\Admin::Banana_Tosser?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such conventions for WP. But I would recommend to use such style:

```
Plugins\Your_Company\Your_Plugin\Your_Component\Your_Class
```